# Cassandra where clause combine SLICE and IN restrictions on clustering keys

Tags: cassandra, cql

I would like to select data using filters on clustering keys.

Particularly I need filters on two clustering keys:

- first clustering key should be restricted with slice filter (like >, >=, <, <=)
- second clustering key should be restricted with IN filter

Using the latest version of cassandra (3.11.0) such filterring does not work.
BTW: did not find this particular restriction in documentation.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testing.t1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing.t1 (
c1 text,
c2 int,
c3 text,
PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3));

INSERT INTO testing.t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('key1',100,'clust1')
INSERT INTO testing.t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('key1',110,'clust1')
INSERT INTO testing.t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('key1',120,'clust2')
INSERT INTO testing.t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('key1',130,'clust3')
INSERT INTO testing.t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('key2',160,'clust2')

SELECT * FROM testing.t1
WHERE c1 = 'key1'
AND c2 > 100
AND c3 IN ('clust2','clust3')
ALLOW FILTERING
```

The query generates the following error:

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="IN restrictions are not supported on indexed columns"

Could you help me clarifying the issue?

Is there a particular reason not to allow such filters or it's kind of remnant of the past?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the excerpt from the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryIN.html):

> The **IN** keyword can define a set of clustering columns to fetch
>   together, supporting a "multi-get" of CQL rows. A single clustering
>   column can be defined if all preceding columns are defined for either
>   equality or group inclusion.

Essentially, you could only use `IN` clause when all previous clustering columns are specified with equality or with `IN` clause as well.

You could, however, use the slice filter after using `IN` clause as long as it is for the last elements of the clustering key.

This restriction is also described in the section **>, >=, <= and < restrictions** of this blog [post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) (it talks about version 2.2 though).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the docs.
As for cases when IN filter is allowed..
You can filter with slice filter not only in the last position. 
The following query works perfectly:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing.t1 (    
    c1 text,
    c2 int,
    c3 int,
    c4 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3, c4));
    
    SELECT * FROM testing.t1
    WHERE c1 = 'key1'
    AND c2 IN (100,110,120,160)
    AND c3 > 1
    AND c4 = 5000
    ALLOW FILTERING`

Comment: I wonder if this is a change in 3.x version or I was confused in a first place.